# iOS app to get data from website's API

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, api, uitableview

I am developing a website and an iOS app. I want the same functionality both at the website and in the app, so I am thinking that the best idea is to develop the infrastructure on the website first.

I am using Node.js and MongoDB, so I want my iOS app to extract data from the MongoDB, but what I am considering is to develop a simple API to which I can send requests from the app. Does it make sense to do so? Are there any concerns about getting data from an API rather than establishing a MongoDB connection in the app?

I am thinking that the API could be as simple as

```
exports.getUserList = (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({}, (err, users) => {
    res.json(users);
  });
};

exports.getUserDetail = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
    res.json(user);
  });
};
```

and in the app, I would make an UITableView which gets populated with the data extracted through the API.

If this is the right approach, I am thinking that I should maybe also integrate the API in the website itself. So instead of having a user list on the website and a user list in the API, it would probably make more sense to also send a request to the API and add the data to the website. Doing everything through the API enables me to only focus on security, validation, user rights, etc. only in the API and not both in the API and elsewhere at the website.

How do developers typically approach the case of both developing a website and an iOS app? Are they really separate projects or can I think of the iOS app as a 'top layer' on top of the website?

Answer (score 0):

For many reasons, you have to use APIs from nodeJS to connect your app to MongoDB:

1) Its safer and more secure to use APIs as a mid-layer between the endpoint and the front-end.

2) Its more scalable, where you can use those APIs for multiple platforms simultaneously as nodeJS is very fast at processing simultaneous requests.

3) On later stage, if you need message queuing (SQS) to handle request bombs from thousands devices, its better to get the data through APIs that will be put in queue and gets processed sequentially.